# Semantic UI events

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I started recently to use the semantic UI framework and I have difficulties understanding how you trigger events.

For instance you can change a drop down list "onchange" event in this way:

```
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown('setting', 'onChange', function(){alert(1)});
```

Now what would you do to add a custom event on an input element? Where is it documented?

Thanks,
Florent

Comment: What do you mean by custom events?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the Semantic UI website and see no "Usage" tab with Javascript examples, that means that there is no built-in jQuery function for that UI component.

Such as input:
http://semantic-ui.com/elements/input.html

In this case, you do everything you need to do via normal jQuery.

```
$('.ui.input input').on('change', function(e) { alert('input changed') });
```

Semantic UI is primarily a CSS framework. It provides Javascript methods mostly in the cases where CSS alone can't do the job (such as `ui popup`) or when there are some discrepancies in how Javascript works between browsers (`click` vs `change` event in `ui checkbox`).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar type of problem. And then when I read the semantic-ui documentation I was able to figure out the problem.
This was for **dropdown**.

Whenever an event is called let say onChange event it returns a callback function

```
onChange(value, text, $choice)
```

**Description:**
Is called after a dropdown value changes. Receives the name and value of selection and the active menu element
Please read the documentation carefully 
[Link to semantic-ui](https://semantic-ui.com)

Thanks